# Export same function with different names and types

Tags: typescript

## Edit

Thanks to @jsejcksn,
I think I solved the problem: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCBDANrgI2wGMBrAGhQwFEAzW9YmStdAZRmxnTgF85aUCCDgByKOhIxRAbgBQc4ADtuUWiR4BxdEvRRgxAEITspSMpgBFZHoCeiOXDgETZiBYBccVDH1KA5vJOAI42ULZePn6BcrwKFnrqxDwAgmBgxpJuFtZ2cOgAHtxKACaocNq6+kau5iq54Q5OLll1MF6iIBAEwLjoonAAPmKcBH3SQ2JKENwEEBCkA8OiJeiopDAQYLKOcKF2kb7KMXGKKokacAAq2L0A7solmaZtDfaFxWUVOnoGz9n1ML2BC7FovdwqDoFVBLMSoECwzolRG4fyIgq4HYhIGHaLyU7ECBKHxwTj3R7-NqoLw3cmlSkQqxAgDaAF04ABeODM3ZIMEA9piaGiSj7cIdAAUIGUAFoHiUYAALLwANgALAAGMAFACUA145F5zlqjI68JFexxYilsvlSq8AHYVQAObV6viGpx8k2eMQgZGiq2iG1KOXABXKuAARg1ACY1W79Z7EMbWqaxKiLWKItbpaG7ZGo7HnVrdUmjfy2lDMYGDrnbeH7dGAKwAZhViY9clZ8jkhOJ8Gw6QZFmpcDSGR9gLsbM53IrU8FnW6vX6tfF9fzjcjrc1nYNC7TvtEo3GWaDIbDEa8zY1pfdB69qfBx+ms3mi3XOeDeavTZj8b7sm3pHpCYirOsmzbF+kq-gWXhFiWQHdr2MC2GAWg-NUI4qAAangNgADxXAAfHOIJOMypDoDmUTHKyNL4qh6E8AASugoTABIJS0rgDz0ou+G4ERpHkXA0I0nwkxIPCkn8MMSD+nJ0lwKiykKeJuByfIaEYXA7GcdxE44TAQkiWRXKKSufTqSmp7oIKVxSRpb7oHMCy2UgEEbFs2kKLQyBKEwwBElQ6AmQAEh+xGULh+RFDoXyVL8NSgaZBHoMRJGUIY8WfOUyXYYubwkRKuzKMAMDAHgZnoDSyYAG4ZV4uHJpWjJjoYbJyDqkkUXA-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-oCd1-D5baeiw5k-fzNMD4n8oFYKoUe5VCWsZRcUUFjT36hPSWAhgFVVClldWmsNr03qrTZq+kOLIC4pjSBaVapZUZuPH+CDWCRQ-Gg9a2sMrmwYXAIck40qg0foAuQAUgrIJpmAvQS0rh3GoTAsh8CabcJATTVBJsME2CwRbLwBl8HcV4rDEyJDSJkKcOIsKIjSC0NNkwi2lAWEmXYbsXgnDCiQFgANIkJJWBEJfCocoXJ+FQAgcOKBNChY2OgPAb6rAhHmLnB4wRwifGiPkEAA)

---

I'm building a function to help me use media queries with the tailwind library.
This library has some predefined named breakpoints like `xs`, `lg`, etc.
But I also want to define my own named breakpoints like `mobile`, `desktop`, etc.

So I have created two "different" functions:

```
interface AppBreakpointQuery {
  breakpoint: 'mobile' | 'tablet' | 'notebook' | 'desktop';
  query: string;
}

interface TailwindBreakpointQuery {
  breakpoint: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl';
  query: string;
}

const tailwindBreakpoints: TailwindBreakpointQuery[] = [
  { breakpoint: 'xs', query: '(min-width: 640px)' },
  { breakpoint: 'sm', query: '(min-width: 768px)' },
  { breakpoint: 'md', query: '(min-width: 1024px)' },
  { breakpoint: 'lg', query: '(min-width: 1280px)' },
  { breakpoint: 'xl', query: '(min-width: 1536px)' },
];

const appBreakpoints: AppBreakpointQuery[] = [
  { breakpoint: 'mobile', query: '(min-width: 340px)' },
  { breakpoint: 'tablet', query: '(min-width: 500px)' },
  { breakpoint: 'notebook', query: '(min-width: 1024px)' },
  { breakpoint: 'desktop', query: '(min-width: 1280px)' },
];

type TailwindBreakpointValue<T> = {
  [key in TailwindBreakpointQuery['breakpoint']]: T;
};

type AppBreakpointValue<T> = {
  [key in AppBreakpointQuery['breakpoint']]: T;
};

function useAppBreakpoint<T>(initialValue: T, value: AppBreakpointValue<T>): T;
function useTailwindBreakpoint<T>(initialValue: T, value: TailwindBreakpointValue<T>): T;
```

The big problem here is that those functions has the exactly same implementation.

I want to know if is possible to export only one function under different names and params (`useAppBreakpoint` and `useTailwindBreakpoint`) without duplicating code.

---

Another simplified example:

Given a function `add` that add it's parameters like

```
function add(a: any, b: any) { return a + b }
```

How do I export this same function as `addOne` and `addTwo`. Something like:

```
type One = 1
type Two = 2

function addOne(a: string, b: One): number;

function addTwo(a: number, b: Two): number;

export {
  add as addOne,
  add as addTwo,
}
```

The idea here is that `addOne === addTwo` should be `true`

Comment: I d willing to bet that you are looking for function overloads https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: @captain-yossarian Overloads require using the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your addition example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCasQCmQLhWATwBpEAjPZQgSjzBAFtSBTAJ0QG8BYAKEURaZQQLJMkQBqMgG4eAXx48oBAA5NEAeTBqAvIgCMilWoAqAdziJdAJgXclqxAEF0mnVlyIAzlBYwwAcxJyDS0qSwA+RDpGVhk7Iyd0MwtdbFoGZhYgvGSw7UjozLieJgAPZTgWKEQIBG8UFy08Z1RXSwbUOLKKqpq66rRUZOak83bBuKA)

```ts
function add (a: any, b: any): number {
  return a + b;
}

type One = 1
type Two = 2

type AddOne = (a: string, b: One) => number;
type AddTwo = (a: number, b: Two) => number;

export const addOne: AddOne = add;
export const addTwo: AddTwo = add;
```